# Telling the difference between a Phonegap build and a local build with the DOM?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have a Phonegap app that I am developing and I would love to be able to tell the difference between one built on their server and one built locally on my machine.

Is there anything in the `DOM` that might give this information away?

Comment: Why not build both and run a diff on them?

Comment: Its purely for development, I want to include different files if it is built locally for debugging.

Comment: Not sure a diff will work on the DOM. How the heck do you do that :p

Comment: Unlikely that you could figure this out from the DOM alone. There might be an iframe in there used for communication over the native bridge, but you couldn't *rely* on that, since there are different mechanisms for native communication.

Comment: It doesn't matter where you build it, the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, whilst its not with the `DOM` its the only way I can see of checking which version I am in...

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'file:///android_asset/www/icon-72-2x.png',
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {
            //file does not exists
        },
        success: function()
        {
            //file exists
        }
    });
```

Only works with Android, but paths can be changed to match iPhone and the other devices as well.